# Using multipart/form-data in Windows metro apps

Tags: forms, http, post

I'm trying to create a way to upload text data (database key) along with an .png image from a Windows 8.1 App, through a multipart/form-data HTTP POST request, to a PHP script hosted on a webserver (which saves the image locally using the database key as a filename)

I've had a look at packet sniffer and it's all coming out the way I think it should, but the problem is that the PHP $_POST value is not passing through and is null on the php script side.

Here is the C# code on the Windows Metro app side:

```
    private async void UploadImage() {

        string newLine = Environment.NewLine;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywebsite.com/receiveimage.php");

        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        request.Method = "POST";

        string boundary = "---------------------BUIUFBILPQMZ81C12CCC2EVV2RJ";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        // Open pre-saved MY_FILE.png file from local disk and store in fh
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile fh = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("MY_FILE.png");

        // Header strings and values
        string Prefix1 = boundary + newLine + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"SERIAL_NO\"" + newLine + newLine; // SERIAL_NO is the php $_POST variable
        string Prefix2 = boundary + newLine + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"MY_FILE\"; filename=\"" +  "MY_FILE.png\"" + newLine + "Content-Type: application/base64" + newLine + newLine;

        byte[] baPrefix1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Prefix1);
        byte[] baValue1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C4145-12" + newLine); // (C4145-12 is the database key)

        IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(fh); 
        byte[] baPrefix2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Prefix1);
        byte[] baValue2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer.ToArray()).Replace("+", "%2B") + newLine);

        byte[] combinedData = new byte[baPrefix1.Length + baValue1.Length + baPrefix2.Length + baValue2.Length];

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(baPrefix1, 0, combinedData, 0, baPrefix1.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(baValue1, 0, combinedData, baPrefix1.Length, baValue1.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(baPrefix2, 0, combinedData, baPrefix1.Length + baValue1.Length, baPrefix2.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(baValue2, 0, combinedData, baPrefix1.Length + baValue1.Length + baPrefix2.Length, baValue2.Length);

        Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

        dataStream.Write(combinedData, 0, combinedData.Length);
        dataStream.Dispose();

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // "STATUS" is just a text block
            STATUS.Text = (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            STATUS.Text = responseFromServer;
        }

    }
```

The PHP script on the server works with other forms but can't recognize the value passed in from this script, so I know it's not an issue with that. I'm convinced it's a problem with the header formatting. I've experimented with the amount of new lines but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: MIME parts are separated by `"--"+boundary`, and the last part is terminated by `"--"+boundary+"--"`. You are missing the leading and terminating `"--"`. Also, you are using `Prefix1` again instead of `Prefix2` when allocating `baPrefix2`. Also, for the PNG, `application/base64` is not a valid content type, you need to use `image/png` instead, and include a separate `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` header. But many webservers do not handle base64 on form-data posts, so you should drop base64 and send the file data as-is as 8bit data. What you have shown is not a good MIME implementation.

Comment: Yep, it turned out to be the missing preceding/trailing "--" next to the boundaries that were throwing it off. It works now, thank you!